# Problem deploying Phoenix app to Gigalixir: "No file named server@127.0.0.1"

Tags: phoenix-framework, gigalixir

I am trying to deploy Hashrockets [TIL Phoenix App](https://github.com/hashrocket/tilex) to [Gigalixir](https://www.gigalixir.com).

This is what I get after push to Gigalixir:

```
2020-08-23T05:58:55.071975+00:00 til[gigalixir-run]: Attempting to start 'til' on host 'til-6c4c5d7854-ddpfh'
2020-08-23T05:58:55.071987+00:00 til[gigalixir-run]: Attempting health checks on port 4000
2020-08-23T05:58:55.874467+00:00 til[til-6c4c5d7854-ddpfh]: web.1  | started with pid 49
2020-08-23T05:58:57.568099+00:00 til[til-6c4c5d7854-ddpfh]: web.1  | No file named server@127.0.0.1
2020-08-23T05:58:57.976006+00:00 til[til-6c4c5d7854-ddpfh]: web.1  | exited with code 1
2020-08-23T05:58:57.976034+00:00 til[til-6c4c5d7854-ddpfh]: system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

I cannot make sense of the error message `No file named server@127.0.0.1`. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this problem is, that the [`Procfile`](https://github.com/hashrocket/tilex/blob/master/Procfile) coming with the project is probably meant to be used with Heroku and contains

```
web: MIX_ENV=prod elixir --cookie $OTP_COOKIE --name server@127.0.0.1 --erl '-kernel inet_dist_listen_min 9000' --erl '-kernel inet_dist_listen_max 9000' -S mix phx.server
```

Renaming the file to `Procfile.disabled` and thus making Gigalixir use its [default `Procfile`](https://github.com/gigalixir/gigalixir-run/blob/master/Procfile) solves this problem.